# Jenkins file and alias

Tags: bash, jenkins

I want to make a multi stage test where I successively test an application with Python 3.10, 3.9, 3.8, etc. I have a docker container with 3 executable available.

- /usr/local/bin/python3.8
- /usr/local/bin/python3.9
- /usr/local/bin/python3.10

I have this section of Jenkinsfile

```
stage ('Test Python 3.10') {
    steps {
        sh ''' 
        echo $(which python3)
        alias python3=python3.10
        echo $(which python3)
        alias pip3=pip3.10
        scripts/check_python_version.sh 3.10 && scripts/runtests.sh
        '''
    }
}
stage ('Test Python 3.9') {
    steps {
        sh ''' 
        alias python3=python3.9
        alias pip3=pip3.9
        scripts/check_python_version.sh 3.9 && scripts/runtests.sh
        '''
    }
}
```

My alias is not taken in account.  Looking at the first stage output, we get

```
+ which python3
+ echo /usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
+ alias python3=python3.10
+ which python3
+ echo /usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
+ alias pip3=pip3.10
+ scripts/check_python_version.sh 3.10
ERROR - Reported python3 version is Python 3.8.13
```

How can I change the default python3 during the Jenkins test stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My alias is not taken in account

Sure it isn't, aliases only affect interactive shell when you type stuff. It do not affect shebang, or kernel, or anything else.

> How can I change the default python3 during the Jenkins test stage?

Create a temporary directory. In that directory create a shell script `python3` file that will call the actual executable. Add that directory to path.

```
mkdir bin
printf "%s\n" "#!/bin/sh" "$(which python3.10)"' "$@"' >> bin/python3
chmod +x bin/python3
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
```

You might be interested in `pyenv`. And you might consider just running your pipelines from docker containers that ship proper python version installed.

Comment: I used a symbolic link and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I finally went for a different approach. I create a venv with Jenkins using the right python then activate it before launching the tests. Much cleaner.